# Cython either marginally faster or slower than pure Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, cython

I am using several techniques (**NumPy**, **Weave** and **Cython**) to perform a Python performance benchmark. What the code basically does mathematically is `C = AB`, where A, B and C are `N x N` matrices (**NOTE:** this is a matrix product and not an element-wise multiplication).

I have written 5 distinct implementations of the code:

1. Pure python (Loop over 2D Python lists)
2. NumPy (Dot product of 2D NumPy arrays)
3. Weave inline (C++ loop over 2D arrays)
4. Cython (Loop over 2D Python lists + static typing)
5. Cython-Numpy (Loop over 2D NumPy arrays + static typing)

My expectation is that implementations 2 through 5 will be substantially faster than implementation 1. My results however indicate otherwise. These are my normalised speed-up results relative to the pure Python implementation:

- python_list: 1.00
- numpy_array: 330.09
- weave_inline: 30.72
- cython_list: 2.80
- cython_array: 0.14

I am quite happy with the performance of NumPy, however I am less enthusiastic about Weave's performance and Cython's performance makes me cry. My entire code is separated over two files. Everything is automated and you simply need to run the first file to see all results. Could someone please aid me by indicating what I could do to obtain better results?

**matmul.py:**

```
import time

import numpy as np
from scipy import weave
from scipy.weave import converters

import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import cython_matmul as cml


def python_list_matmul(A, B):
    C = np.zeros(A.shape, dtype=float).tolist()
    A = A.tolist()
    B = B.tolist()
    for k in xrange(len(A)):
        for i in xrange(len(A)):
            for j in xrange(len(A)):
                C[i][k] += A[i][j] * B[j][k]
    return C


def numpy_array_matmul(A, B):
    return np.dot(A, B)


def weave_inline_matmul(A, B):
    code = """
       int i, j, k;
       for (k = 0; k < N; ++k)
       {
           for (i = 0; i < N; ++i)
           {
               for (j = 0; j < N; ++j)
               {
                   C(i, k) += A(i, j) * B(j, k);
               }
           }
       }
       """

    C = np.zeros(A.shape, dtype=float)
    weave.inline(code, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'N'], type_converters=converters.blitz, compiler='gcc')
    return C


N = 100
A = np.random.rand(N, N)
B = np.random.rand(N, N)

function = []
function.append([python_list_matmul, 'python_list'])
function.append([numpy_array_matmul, 'numpy_array'])
function.append([weave_inline_matmul, 'weave_inline'])
function.append([cml.cython_list_matmul, 'cython_list'])
function.append([cml.cython_array_matmul, 'cython_array'])

t = []
for i in xrange(len(function)):
    t1 = time.time()
    C = function[i][0](A, B)
    t2 = time.time()
    t.append(t2 - t1)
    print function[i][1] + ' \t: ' + '{:10.6f}'.format(t[0] / t[-1])
```

**cython_matmul.pyx:**

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

import cython
cimport cython

DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef cython_list_matmul(A, B):

    cdef int i, j, k
    cdef int N = len(A)

    A = A.tolist()
    B = B.tolist()
    C = np.zeros([N, N]).tolist()

    for k in xrange(N):
        for i in xrange(N):
            for j in xrange(N):
                C[i][k] += A[i][j] * B[j][k]
    return C


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.nonecheck(False)
cpdef cython_array_matmul(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] A, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] B):

    cdef int i, j, k, N = A.shape[0]
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] C = np.zeros([N, N], dtype=DTYPE)

    for k in xrange(N):
        for i in xrange(N):
            for j in xrange(N):
                C[i][k] += A[i][j] * B[j][k]
    return C
```

Comment: You're only running the code once as far as I can tell.  This biases your results again things like `weave` as during that first computation, `weave` needs to actually compile the inline code -- Subsequent calls will likely bypass this really expensive step because I think the inline code will be cached.

Comment: Yes it is true that the written code executes only once, however I make sure to run the code several times when I change something.

Comment: Why are you using an explicit looping for the Cython-Numpy? If I'm not mistaken including `np.import_array()` would allow you to use Numpy's C API and call `np.PyArray_MatrixProduct2(A, B, C)` instead of performing your looping. (Or would that obviate the need for your cython function to begin with?) Using `np.matrix` instead of `np.ndarray` may affect performance as well but I'm not sure how much.

Comment: Up until now I have only used basic Python and basic Numpy. I have no familiarity with the C API of Python nor Numpy. So there is my reason. But thank you for pointing that out. I might start to dig somewhat deeper and get my hands dirty by squeezing everything out that there is to get.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python lists and high performance math are incompatible, forget about `cython_list_matmul`.

The only problem with your `cython_array_matmul` is incorrect usage of indexing. It should be

```
C[i,k] += A[i,j] * B[j,k]
```

That's how numpy arrays are indexed in Python and that's the syntax Cython optimizes.
With this change you should get decent performance.

Cython's [annotation feature](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types) is really helpful in spotting optimization problems like this one. You could notice that `A[i][j]` produces a ton of Python API calls, while `A[i,j]` produces none.

Also, if you initialize all entries by hand, `np.empty` is more appropriate than `np.zeros`.

Comment: Nikita - here I thought I was a numpy expert, and I didn't know about np.empty. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Nikita, that did the trick. I have a speed-up of around 70x with `cython_array_matmul`. Is there a way to make it even faster? Using pointer arithmetics perhaps? @Rick, its wonderful how you can always learn new stuff no matter how big a pro you are :).

Comment: Mandating a contiguous buffer (`[mode='c']`) may win a little bit, but at this point you would switch to a modern cache-oblivious algorithm, go multithreaded and rewrite in SIMD assembly...
Or just use an optimized BLAS implementation (for example, Intel MKL).

Comment: [OpenBLAS](http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/) is free and is comparable to MKL speed-wise